# Trying to modify <td> elements in only the first columns -- changing its class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a table, a datatable to be precise. Which is getting created, I have Computer Names in the first columns and prices on all the columns after. I am using the jquery plug in jquery.dataTables.editable and jquery.jeditable.

Here is a simple diagram to prove my point.

```
Column 1 | Column 2
--------------------
Apples   | 44%
--------------------
Bananas  | 23%
--------------------
Oranges  | 13%
--------------------
Other    | 10%
--------------------
```

The actual  elements do not have a class associated with them. I need to get ONLY column 1 elements to have a class of "read_only"

This table is dynamically generated so it needs to happen in javascript. 
This is what I was trying

```
$('tr').each(function(){
       if($("tr:first-child")){
           $(this).attr("class", "read_only");
       }
    });
```

This was in the $(document).read(function(){}, after I initialize my datatable.

Any suggestions on what I need to do?

Comment: Try `$(this).find('td').eq(0).addClass('read_only');`

Comment: $('tr td:first-child').addClass('read_only');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using datatables it's easy to add class during initialization like this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumns":
 [
    { "sClass": "my_class" }, //class for the first column
    null,
    null     
 ]
 } );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
$(function() {
    $("tr td:eq(0)").addClass("read_only");
});
```

At document ready it will find the first td (0 based index) in each row and add the class `read_only`.

I'd recommend giving the table either an ID or class that you can reference in the call as well, just in case you have any other tables on the same page.

Obviously, if you need to remove any existing classes then change it to `.attr("class", "read_only")` instead of `addClass`, as you previously had.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding a CSS class, why not just target the first-child on the td?

```
#tableID tr td:first-child {

}
```

Don't even need jquery

If you really want to add a class you can do the same

```
$('#tableID tr td:first-child');
```